# This simple code is not working and I really don't know why

Tags: javascript, html

I think this has all the needed info:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqMYa.png]

I have checked all the syntax I know and I cannot believe that I cannot figure out something this simple. Pls help!

Comment: did you read the error at the bottom of the picture?

Comment: Please post text, not pictures. When you ask questions you need to include all relevant information. Here, since you're interacting with the DOM, including the HTML you think you're working with would also be prudent.

Comment: You don't have the element with id `demo` in your page when you run that script. Can you add the `test` file content to your question? My guess would be that you run the script before all your html markup.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the console shows that `document.getElementById("demo")` is null, which suggests that your HTML doesn't have an element with the id attribute set to "demo".

Make sure your HTML includes something like this:

```
<p id="demo">This text will be replaced by Javascript.</p>
```

Comment: (Or the code is running before the DOM is rendered.)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities,

No element with the ID demo is found. Create an element

```
<div id="demo">Temperature goes here</div>
```

Your code is being executed before DOM loads

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Your JS here to calculate Fahrenheit
});
```

Hope this helps